# Martial Status issue with Tax Calculator

Tags: java, boolean

I am having issues with determining the martial status of the input. I wrote it originally to only account for someone who is single. How can I change the tax rate based on whether or not the person is married?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncomeCalc {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner fetch = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Gross Annual Pay: ");
        double grossPay = fetch.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your State Tax in Decimal Form: ");
        float tax = fetch.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Are you Married (Y/N): ");
        String status = fetch.next();
        double fedTax = 0;

        if (grossPay >= 518401 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .37 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 612351 && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .37 * grossPay;   
        } else if (grossPay >= 207351 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .35 * grossPay;   
        } else if (grossPay >= 408201 && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .35 * grossPay;   
        } else if (grossPay >= 163301 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .32 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 321451 && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .32 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 85526 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .24 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 168401  && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .24 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 40126 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .22 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 78951  && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .22 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 9875 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .12 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 19401  && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .12 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 0 && status == "N") {
            fedTax = (float) .10 * grossPay;
        } else if (grossPay >= 0 && status == "Y") {
            fedTax = (float) .10 * grossPay;
        } else {
            System.out.println(":(");
        }

        float stateTaxes  = (float) (grossPay * tax);
        float netPay = (float) (grossPay - stateTaxes - fedTax);
        System.out.print("Your monthly household income is: " + netPay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare strings. Use `equals()`. Also, it's marital status. Martial status is when you know kung-fu.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper: but after you have been married for a while, the two ("martial" and "marital") sort of merge